# How can load the Docker section of my Jenkins pipeline (Jenkinsfile) from a file?

Tags: docker, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have multiple pipelines using Jenkinsfiles that retrieve a docker image from a private registry. I would like to be able to load the docker specific information into the pipelines from a file, so that I don’t have to modify all of my Jenkinsfiles when the docker label or credentials change. I attempted to do this using the example jenkinsfile below:

```
def common

pipeline {
   agent none
   options {
     timestamps()
   }
   stages {
    stage('Image fetch') {
     steps{
        script {
              common = load('/home/jenkins/workspace/common/docker_image')
              common.fetchImage()
        }
     }
  }
}
```

With docker_image containing:

```
def fetchImage() {
  agent {
   docker {
    label “target_node ”
    image 'registry-url/image:latest'
    alwaysPull true
    registryUrl 'https://registry-url’
    registryCredentialsId ‘xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx’
   }
  }
}
```

I got the following error when I executed the pipeline:

> Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing Perhaps you forgot
>   to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as:
>   node,dockerNode

How can I do this using a declarative pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with this:

1. You can allocate a `node` only at top level

   ```groovy
   pipeline {
     agent ...
   }
   ```

   Or you can use a per-stage node allocation like so:

   ```groovy
   pipeline {
     agent none
     ....
     stages {
       stage("My stage") {
         agent ...
         steps {
           // run my steps on this agent
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   You can check the docs [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent-example)
2. The `steps` are supposed to be executed on the allocated node (or in some cases they can be executed without allocating a node at all).
3. `Declarative Pipeline` and `Scripted Pipeline` are two different things. Yes, it's possible to mix them, but `scripted pipeline` is meant to either abstract some logic into a [shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/), or to provide you a way to be a "hard core master ninja" and write your own fully custom pipeline using the `scripted` pipeline and none of the `declarative` sugar.

I am not sure how your `Docker <-> Jenkins` connection is setup, but you would probably be better if you install a plugin and use `agent templates`  to provide the agents you need.

If you have a `Docker Swarm` you can install the [Docker Swarm Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Swarm+Plugin) and then in your pipeline you can just configure `pipeline { agent { label 'my-agent-label' } }`. This will automatically provision your Jenkins with an agent in a container which uses the image you specified.

If you have exposed `/var/run/docker.sock` to your Jenkins, then you could use [Yet Another Docker Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/yet-another-docker-plugin), which has the same concept.

This way you can remove the agent configuration into the `agent template` and your pipeline will only use a `label` to have the agent it needs.

Comment: I'm not allocating a node at all. I don't have a problem allocating agents. My problem is that I have lots of Jenkinsfiles that retrieve the same docker image. I would like to load the docker section of my pipeline from a single file, so that I don't have to modify all of my Jenkinsfiles if I need to add or remove a Docker parameter.

Comment: The way you can do this is by installing one of the two plugins I mentioned. You then `define` the agent template with a `label` and you just allocate the node with the `label` you gave it.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, I don't have admin access to our Jenkins installation, so I can't create Docker agent templates.

Comment: That is unfortunate. I don't think it's possible to do this programatically (i.e. via groovy). You could try asking this at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org - there might be some really hidden feature which makes this possible, but from my experience you will hit a wall.